# How to use im2rec in MXnet to create my own dataset

Tags: windows, python-2.7, mxnet

In windows 10, I followed the step-by-step MXnet tutorial to use im2rec.py to create a dataset. I created a image list file like this:

```
integer_image_index \t label_index \t path_to_image
```

> [image]

Next, I modified `.txt` to `.lst`.

> [image]

Finally, I executed the command:

```
python im2rec.py --exts '.jpg' --train-ratio 0.41 --test-ratio 0.49 --recursive=True --pack-label=True D:\CUB_200_2011\data\image_label.lst D:\CUB_200_2011\CUB_200_2011\image
```

It is shown that "read no error", but the files created by the command like `.lst` and `.rec` are 0K, there is empty. I don't know why.

Please tell me what mistakes I made.

Comment: Can you copy/past the full error message(s) you're seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`im2rec.py` will print

`read none error:`(filename)

for any file that it can't load for whatever reason.  Maybe some of the files you list aren't there or are empty?  Or maybe the base path you've specified is wrong -- I notice you have the folder name `CUB_200_2011` twice.

Comment: I have modified the code in im2rec.py and a mistake about path.Now it works well.Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sure thing!  I also improved the error messaging in `im2rec`: https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet/pull/3942 so hopefully this will be more clear in the future.

Comment: I get the following error in Windows 10, x64: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MXIndexedRecordIO', what should I do to create my own dataset?